How to use Gdk.Rgba.new in SML with Giraffe
val red_color = Gdk.Rgba.new { red = 1.0, green = 0.0, blue = 0.0, alpha = 1.0 }

val color_button = Gtk.ColorButton.newWithRgba(red_color)
I used the example given in the code document to code like this, but it still gives an error
ERROR Msg

/usr/bin/ld: example-2-polyml.o:(.data+0x5a8): undefined reference to giraffe_gdk_rgba_size /usr/bin/ld: example-2-polyml.o:(.data+0x618): undefined reference to giraffe_gdk_rgba_alpha_offset /usr/bin/ld: example-2-polyml.o:(.data+0x648): undefined reference to giraffe_gdk_rgba_blue_offset /usr/bin/ld: example-2-polyml.o:(.data+0x678): undefined reference to giraffe_gdk_rgba_green_offset /usr/bin/ld: example-2-polyml.o:(.data+0x6a8): undefined reference to giraffe_gdk_rgba_red_offset
How should I solve it?
